# Visual Studio C# not identifying closing braces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor

I'm working with Visual Studio, making a .CSHTML web page.
The code was working code. Through some unknown edit? or bug?(unlikely)
Visual studio will not recognize the last set of {}.
 The ones that start with 
@{ C# code here

}

Compiler Error:
"Parser Error Message: The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Source Error:

Line 2:
Line 3:
Line 4:  @{
Line 5:              var db = Database.Open("DevDbCS");
Line 6:
"

I have copy and pasted my code to notepad ++ that highlights the corresponding bracket if I select one. I have confirmed that all brakes open and close correctly. I even dropped it into Processing, (wont compile) but it says all good too.

```
@{
        var db = Database.Open("DevDbCS");

        var selectThorneID = "SELECT ThorneID, Status FROM Batch_Record WHERE Status = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY ThorneID ASC";

        //Variables
        var ThorneID = " ";
        var frmInsertV = "";
        var frmInsert = "";
        var frmUpdate = "";
        var StartUnits = "";
        var EndUnits = "";
        var yield = "";
        var formValues = new double[29];//array for holding results from Query
        var QC = "";
        int RecordCount = 0;

        var sqlfrmValues = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();


        if (IsPost)
        {

            switch (Request.Form["userInput"])
            {
                case "Submit":
                    ThorneID = Request.Form["ThorneID"];
                    StartUnits = Request.Form["s12"];
                    EndUnits = Request.Form["s15"];
                    yield = Request.Form["s17"];
                    QC = Request.Form["QC"];

                    //Set to zero to avoid trying to put nulls in DB
                    if (Request.Form["s12"] == null)
                    {
                        StartUnits = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StartUnits = Request.Form["s12"];
                    }

                    if (Request.Form["s15"] == null)
                    {
                        EndUnits = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EndUnits = Request.Form["s15"];
                    }

                    if (Request.Form["s17"] == null)
                    {
                        yield = "0";
                    }
                    else {
                        yield = Request.Form["s17"];
                    }

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
                    {
                        //set to 1 to keep NaN from appearing, cant divide by zero
                        var itemStr = "var" + i.ToString();
                        var rfTemp = "";
                        if (Request.Form[itemStr] == null)
                        {
                            rfTemp = "0";
                            if (i == 3)
                            {
                                rfTemp = "1";
                            }
                            if (i == 10)
                            {
                                rfTemp = "1";
                            }
                            if (i == 16)
                            {
                                rfTemp = "1";
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rfTemp = Request.Form[itemStr];
                        }

                        //put commas after 1st variable in the string for SQL
                        if (i != 1)
                        {
                            frmUpdate += ", ";
                            frmInsert += ", ";
                            frmInsertV += ", ";
                        }


                        frmUpdate += "s" + i + "= " + rfTemp;
                        frmInsertV += "s" + i;
                        frmInsert += rfTemp;

                    }

                    var UPSERTcommand = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "') "
                                        + "UPDATE YieldEncap SET " + frmUpdate + ", QC='" + QC + "' "
                                        + "WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "' "
                                        + "ELSE "
                                        + "INSERT INTO YieldEncap (ThorneID, QC, " + frmInsertV + ") "
                                        + "VALUES (" + ThorneID + ", '" + QC + "', " + frmInsert + ")";
                    db.Execute(UPSERTcommand);


                    UPSERTcommand = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BR_Details_Yield WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "') "
                                       + "UPDATE BR_Details_Yield SET Department = 'Encap', Units = 'g', StartUnits = '" + StartUnits + "', EndUnits = '" + EndUnits + "', Yield = '" + yield + "' "
                                       + "WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "' "
                                       + "ELSE "
                                       + "INSERT INTO BR_Details_Yield (Department, Units, StartUnits, EndUnits, Yield) "
                                       + "VALUES ('Encap', 'Bottles', " + StartUnits + ", " + EndUnits + ", " + yield + ")";
                    db.Execute(UPSERTcommand);
                    UPSERTcommand = "";

                    sqlfrmValues = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();
                    RecordCount = (int)db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'");

                    //read out the values from sqlfrmValues and place them in an array
                    if (RecordCount > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
                        {
                            if (sqlfrmValues[0][i] != null)
                            {
                                formValues[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sqlfrmValues[0][i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                formValues[i] = 0;
                            }

                        }
                        QC = Convert.ToString(sqlfrmValues[0][27]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formValues[2] = 1;
                        formValues[10] = 1;
                        formValues[16] = 1;
                        formValues[19] = 1;
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    ThorneID = Request.Form["ThorneID"];

                    sqlfrmValues = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();
                    var RecordCount2 = (db.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YieldEncap WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'").Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();

                    if (RecordCount[0][0] > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
                        {
                            if (sqlfrmValues[0][i] != null)
                            {
                                formValues[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sqlfrmValues[0][i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                formValues[i] = 0;
                            }

                        }
                        QC = Convert.ToString(sqlfrmValues[0][27]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        formValues[6] = 1;
                        formValues[8] = 1;
                        formValues[11] = 1;
                        formValues[24] = 1;
                    }
                    //lookup for previous worksheet. Starting point value
                    //var sqlMixing = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldMixing WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();
                    //var sqlMixingRecordCount = (int)db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YieldMixing WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'");
                    //if (sqlMixingRecordCount > 0)
                    //{

                    //    var temp = Convert.ToDouble(sqlfrmValues[0][1]);
                    //    formValues[1] = Convert.ToDouble(sqlMixing[0][1]);

                    //}

                    var sqlMixing = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldMixing WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();
                    RecordCount = (int)db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YieldMixing WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'");
                    if (RecordCount > 0)
                    {
                        formValues[24] = Convert.ToDouble(sqlMixing[0][2]);
                        formValues[24] = formValues[24] * 1000;
                    }

                    break;

            }

        }
    }
```

When it gets to my !DOCTYPE html it tells me "The type or namespace name 'DOCTYPE' could not be could not be found....)
Likely because it cant figure out where the closing brace is.

Where have I gone wrong? It is very frustrating that the compilers message isnt being helpful because all the braces are correct!

Comment: maybe it's a brace outside of this block that's interfering?

Comment: Please use parameterized SQL statements instead of string concatenation. You are opening your application up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Writing complex code inside a Razor view is often going to lead to these issues because the compiler is trying to deal with markup and code blocks, and someone is going to get confused.  In short, don't do this. Pull the code into controller or code behind (or better yet other classes that are called by the UI) so the compiler only has to deal with code.

Comment: I remember seeing one of the MS developers for Razor basically saying parsing Razor is extremely complicated.  I have run into strange issues that can only be solved by fussing with the structure until I found something that doesn't upset the compiler.  I'd definitely very strongly agree with dbugger.  You are absolutely putting the wrong type of code on the Razor page!  I would not even call this a difference of opinions/style. It was never really intended to house your DB and business logic. That's what controllers are for, and even thin controller approaches move that to business+DB layers.

Comment: @DanielMann "Please use parameterized SQL statements instead of string concatenation. You are opening your application up to SQL injection vulnerabilities." 

How am I open when form variables are being stored into an array of doubles, then being dumped out of the array into a string by the server, for the SQL?

Comment: if you are doing a case statement and have more than `1` action or assignment, to make it more readable wrap the code for example in your `case "Submit": {  }` should be used along with using the proper `break;` key word to get out of the case.. this hard to read in it's current state..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove the opening parenthesis between the equal sign and the db variable in this line:

```
var RecordCount2 = (db.Query ....
```

This doesn't have a matching closing parenthesis. Because of that the compiler can't match the curly braces afterwards to the opening ones and shows a misleading error

Comment: Seems to match just fine : var sqlMixing = (db.Query("SELECT * FROM YieldMixing WHERE ThorneID = '" + ThorneID + "'")).Cast<DynamicRecord>().ToArray();

Comment: You're right @Dan Orlovsky I've got mixed up with all those db.Query lines and copied the wrong one from the source code. I changed the answer and included the correct line